# insertTimeRanges:ofTracks:atTime:error:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am trying to merge multiple audio files with multiple clips.I've successfully added multiple videos but I am not able to add multiple audio files.I tried the following way and got the error "__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil".I also tried it by adding AVURLAsset but I got the error "[AVURLAsset asset]: unrecognized selector sent to instance".The app is getting crashed at last line of this code.Please figure out the solution or give an example of 
 `- (BOOL)insertTimeRanges:(NSArray *)timeRanges ofTracks:(NSArray *)tracks atTime:(CMTime)startTime error:(NSError **)error`

```
NSMutableArray *audioUrlArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *audioTimeRangesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
CMTime audioTime = kCMTimeZero;
for (int i = 0; i < self.selectedSongsArray.count; i++)
{
    MPMediaItem * songItem = [self.selectedSongsArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSURL *songURL = [songItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    AVURLAsset *audioUrl = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:songURL options:nil];        
    AVAssetTrack *track = [[audioUrl tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];        
    AVAsset *audioAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:songURL];
    [audioUrlArray addObject:track];
    CMTimeRange timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(audioTime, audioAsset.duration);
    [audioTimeRangesArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTimeRange:timeRange]];
}
AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[audioTrack insertTimeRanges:audioTimeRangesArray ofTracks:audioUrlArray atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, add a mutable array to hold the AVURLAsset.  Once the for loop ends, ARC is collecting the AVURLAsset and the bits you are storing are being destroyed with it.